# Windows 8.1 password issues

Tags: windows-8, passwords

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a single machine, linked to a live account. Every time, yes literally every time without fail, that I turn it on and attempt to log in I either get a username/password incorrect or if it's offline a PC offline use last password on this machine message. If I put in the password a second time it usually works. I know that 99% of the time when users whine 'I put the password in right' they have typed it wrong, but this is a couple of times a day for over a year and I'm sure I type it right the first time and I check that I did. Any idea what's going on? Thanks

Comment: Are you on Wireless?  Are you sure the network connection is up and active by the first time you try?  like say you turn it on, only instead of trying to log in right away, if you wait 5 minutes does it work first try?

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you're etering true password (use that "eye" icon to see what you entered).

If you're sure that you write correct password, then it can be malware which steals your password.
In that case scan your computer for malware (with strong antivirus), and first of all check your startup programs using [Autoruns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963902.aspx). (And if you are not good at analyzing infected computer, call someone for help)